# how to manage multiple radio button options using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, radio-group

Actually I am in react and I have created a banking website so, in this, I have created two options for users that are `choose national banks` and `choose international banks`. both have 3-3 banks to choose anyone from the list and list is radio buttons. but I want that user can choose any one type like if a user is select any banks from `choose national banks` then it selects any banks from `choose international banks` then `choose national banks` selected banks automatically should be unchecked and it is visa-versa. Please help me and suggest a solution for these conditions

here the code:   choose national banks

```
<h1> choose national banks</h1>
<FormGroup
  check
  style={{
 fontSize: "20px",
marginBottom: "2%"}}>
<CustomInput
type="radio"
id="exCustomRadio"
name="customRadio"
label={b1}
value={b1}
checked={cashpointoption ==="b1"}
 onChange={e => {
setnationalbankOption(e.target.value);
  );
}}
/>
<CustomInput
type="radio"
id="exCustomRadio"
name="customRadio"
label={b2}
value={b2}
checked={cashpointoption ==="b2"}
 onChange={e => {
setnationalbankOption(e.target.value);
  );
}}
/>
</FormGroup>
```

choose international banks

```
<h1> choose international banks</h1>
<FormGroup
  check
  style={{
 fontSize: "20px",
marginBottom: "2%"}}>
<CustomInput
type="radio"
id="exCustomRadio"
name="customRadio"
label={b1}
value={b1}
checked={cashpointoption ==="b1"}
 onChange={e => {
setnationalbankOption(e.target.value);
  );
}}
/>
<CustomInput
type="radio"
id="exCustomRadio"
name="customRadio"
label={b2}
value={b2}
checked={cashpointoption ==="b2"}
 onChange={e => {
setnationalbankOption(e.target.value);
  );
}}
/>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: Please format your code. Proper indentation goes a long way.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl can you please suggest any solutions?

Comment: Your question is not understandable. Can you please edit the question so I can get an overview of what you are trying to achieve?